# Why is this function working without a return statement

Tags: javascript, function

This code is used to create Roll and dice game.

```
function nextPlayer() {
    roundScore = 0;
    document.getElementById('current-' + activePlayer).textContent = '0';

    activePlayer === 0? activePlayer = 1: activePlayer = 0; 
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything, so I doubt that the code that calls the function uses the return value.

Comment: functions aren't required to return anything, they can just do stuff (especially when the DOM is in play)

Answer (score 0):

> To return a value other than the default, a function must have a return statement that specifies the value to return. **A function without a return statement will return a default value**. In the case of a constructor called with the new keyword, the default value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, **the default return value is undefined**.

From the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description) (emphasis mine).

In short, you can imagine the function is actually written as:

```
function nextPlayer() {
    [...]
    return undefined;
};
```

Note, this is also equivalent to `return`ing with no value:

```
function nextPlayer() {
    [...]
    return;
};
```